# Group data according to different sequences of numbers -- count specific permutations of interest

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

There are four sequences of numbers that I am interested in:

```
Clockwise
1->2
2->3
3->4
4->1

Counterclockwise
1->4
4->3
3->2
2->1

Opposite
1->3
3->1
2->4
4->2

Repeat
1->1
2->2
3->3
4->4
```

I want to count the number of times each of these sequence groups occur in the `Choice` column of my data for each `Person`.

Here is my data:

```
df <- structure(list(Time = 1:28, Person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Choice = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

[image]

In this dataset, looking at row 1 -> row 2 is considered `Clockwise`, so one count is added to `Clockwise` for Person 1. row 2 -> row 3 is `Counterclockwise`, etc.

How can I achieve this without writing if-else for each and every conditions?

**Expected result**

[image]

Comment: please add the "desired/ expected" "outcome/ result"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff` to get the difference of consecutive rows. Each of your categories corresponds to a particular case of `diff(Choice) %% 4` . 0 ='Repeat', 1 = 'Clockwise', 2 ='Opposite',3 ='Counterclockwise'. Then you can classify it into categories using `cut`:

Edit: I've modified the code to match the desired output

```
df %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(Sequence=
           c(diff(Choice) %% 4,NA) %>%
           cut(breaks=4,labels = c('Repeat','Clockwise','Opposite','Counterclockwise'))
         ) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
  group_by(Person,Sequence)%>%
  summarise(Count=n())

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups:   Person [?]
# Person Sequence         Count
# <int> <fct>            <int>
#   1      1 Repeat               4
# 2      1 Clockwise            5
# 3      1 Opposite             1
# 4      1 Counterclockwise     3
# 5      2 Repeat               3
# 6      2 Clockwise            4
# 7      2 Opposite             2
# 8      2 Counterclockwise     4
```

Comment: Fantastic solution. `mod 4` does exactly what I need, but the entire code needs a bit of modification since it gives me a wrong classification on the very first element as it compares the first row to itself and then outputs `Repeat`. This is incorrect. Furthermore, I do not want to append the result to the original dataset. I want to have the number of classifications for each `Person`. Please have a look at my `Expected result`. Thank you for the great solution.

Comment: I've modified the code based on what you said. `diff` always returns a vector of length 1 less than the input. So, something needs to be appended to it to make it a valid statement. In this case, I've appended an `NA` and then filtered it out. Also, this does not modify your original table and can be stored seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try: also using `?diff` and `base::` functions.

```
ans <- c(NA, diff(df$Choice))
ans[ans %in% c(1,-3)] <- "cw"; ans[ans %in% c(-1,3)] <- "ccw"; ans[ans  %in% 0] <- "rep"; ans[ans %in% c(-2,2)] <- "op"

df$result <- ans

tapply(df$result, df$Person, table)
```

results:

```
#   Time Person Choice result
#1     1      1      1   <NA>
#2     2      1      2     cw
#3     3      1      1    ccw
#4     4      1      2     cw
#5     5      1      1    ccw
#6     6      1      1    rep
#7     7      1      3     op
#8     8      1      4     cw
#9     9      1      1     cw
#10   10      1      4    ccw
#11   11      1      4    rep
#12   12      1      1     cw
#13   13      1      1    rep
#14   14      1      1    rep
#15   15      2      4    ccw
#16   16      2      4    rep
#17   17      2      3    ccw
#18   18      2      4     cw
#19   19      2      1     cw
#20   20      2      4    ccw
#21   21      2      2     op
#22   22      2      3     cw
#23   23      2      1     op
#24   24      2      4    ccw
#25   25      2      4    rep
#26   26      2      1     cw
#27   27      2      1    rep
#28   28      2      4    ccw
```

and:

```
#$`1`    <- person 1
#
#ccw  cw  op rep 
#  3   5   1   4
#
#$`2`    <- person 2
#
#ccw  cw  op rep 
#  5   4   2   3
```